# ARM template with KeyVault accessPolicies for different resource types

Tags: azure, templates, copy

I would like to add accessPolicies to an Azure KeyVault using an ARM template.

I know I can provide an array of objectids to the template and use a `"copy"` element to iterate over them, creating all of the accessPolicies.

But what I would rather do is provide arrays of resource names for resources that are also used for other templates and acquire the objectids at 'run-time' using the `resourceId()` function. So an array of usergroup names and an array of website names for instance.

I have this working for a single resource type, like this:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
    "name": "[concat(variables('keyvault_name'), '/add')]",
    "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
    "dependsOn": [ 
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyvault_name'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "accessPolicies",
                "count": "[length(variables('allowed_websites_names'))]",
                "input": {
                    "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('allowed_websites_names')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')]), '2019-08-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
                    "tenantId": "[variables('tenant_id')]",
                    "permissions": {
                        "keys": [],
                        "secrets": [
                            "Get"
                        ],
                        "certificates": []
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }  
}
```

The `allowed_websites_names` array provides the names of the `Microsoft.Web/sites` resource, the objectids are determined and everything is fine.

If I now have another array of a different resource type, say `Microsoft.Web/sites/slots`, I need to be able to vary the first parameter of the `resourceId()` function (and even add an additional parameter in this specific case).

How can I achieve this? I've already tried the following:

- Duplicate the `/add` fragment, which is not allowed.
- Duplicate the `"copy"` fragment, but then only the last `"copy"` fragment seems to be applied.
- Add another `"accessPolicies"` fragment within the `"copy"` fragment, but then I get a duplication error.

Is passing in 'raw' objectIds, which I then need to determine somewhere else, really the only way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: It sounds like you might be able to do what you're wanting in Bicep, since you can add reference functions in variables (and cannot in the ARM template). You could make a variable that contained the `reference()`s and then use the copy function on that

Comment: That sounds like it would be a solution indeed. Looking into bicep crossed my mind just after I posted this question, but I did not have the time for it yet. Thanks!